# should productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: run when there is no internet connection?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

Im implementing a store in my iphone game.  When I have an internet connection is seems to work perfectly.  However, When I turn my phone to airplane mode to test the store with no internet connection, productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: still runs.

I have also implemented request:didFailWithError: but it never gets called.

Shouldn't productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: not run when my iphone isnt connected to the internet, or will it always run no matter what?  If it shouldn't be running...any ideas why it is?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Is it perhaps returning a cached response?

Comment: @CarlVeazey, I have the same problem. I have removed my app from the device, also cleaned the product from xcode. The problem still occured, so the problem should not be because of the cached response. Any further idea?